# Selectively dump object attributes with PyYAML

Tags: python, serialization, yaml, pyyaml

I can use YAML to dump a hierarchy of python objects, so:

```
import yaml

class C():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class D():
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

d = D(c=C(x=1, y='hi'),
      d='bye')

print yaml.dump(d)
```

produces the output:

```
!!python/object:__main__.D
c: !!python/object:__main__.C {x: 1, y: hi}
d: bye
```

But I want to selectively hide some attributes.  So suppose I have a function `attribs_to_dump(obj)` which for any object returns the list of attribute names I want to dump, for example:

```
def attribs_to_dump(obj):
    if obj.__class__ == C: return ['x']
    if obj.__class__ == D: return ['c']
```

My question is, how do I hook `attribs_to_dump` into `yaml.dump` so that I get the following output?

```
!!python/object:__main__.D
c: !!python/object:__main__.C {x: 1}
```

There's a complicating factor: I want to achieve the effect by hooking into Yaml as it crawls over the object hierarchy rather than by pre-processing the object hierarchy myself.  The reason is that not all objects in the hierarchy are easily amenable to introspection due to `setattr/getattr/__dict__` magic that is present in some libraries I am using :-(...

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, I enjoyed solving it, thanks :)

```
from copy import deepcopy


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class D(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

d = D(
    c=C(x=1, y='hi'),
    d='bye'
)


FILTER_PARAMS = (
    #(class_reference, process_recursively, ['attributes', 'on', 'whitelist'])
    (D, True, ['c']),
    (C, False, ['x']),
)

def attr_filter(obj, filter_params):
    for attr in dir(obj):
        if attr.startswith('__'):
            # ignore builtins
            continue

        attr_val = obj.__getattribute__(attr)
        # loop through filter params
        for (cls, do_recursive, whitelist) in filter_params:
            if isinstance(obj, cls) and attr in whitelist:
                # filter class matches the current obj's class and
                # current attribute is on the whitelist
                if do_recursive:
                    # must process this attribute the same way as the parent
                    setattr(obj, attr, attr_filter(attr_val, filter_params))                
                # break will avoid the execution of the else clause meaning
                # the attribute was on the white list so don't delete it
                break
        else:
            # delete the current attribute of the instance as it was
            # not on the whitelist
            delattr(obj, attr)

    return obj


# do a deepcopy of the object you pass in, so the original will be preserved
filtered_instance = attr_filter(deepcopy(d), FILTER_PARAMS)
print dir(filtered_instance)
print dir(filtered_instance.c)

# now pass filtered_instance to yaml's dump function
```

Comment: You have indeed provided an answer to my question, however in my case deepcopy won't work because the objects I'm serialising are very magical - metaclass magic and very esoteric getattr/setattr overrides.  I need to add some more rules to the game in the question.